# How is the Mongodb change stream update description calculated?

Tags: mongodb, changestream

Our team is looking into adopting more features related to Mongodb change streams.

But related to this, we are wondering what algorithm MongoDB uses to calculate the change stream update description?

The output is an object containing 3 keys:

- updatedFields
- removedFields
- truncatedArrays

`updatedFields` can for example look like this

```js
// When updating:
{
   someArrayOfObjects: [
     {
         innerArray: [
            {completed: true}
         ]
     }
  ]
}

// Results in
{
  'someArrayOfObjects.0.innerArray.0.completed': true
}
```

The reason for the interest in how this is calculated is that we are thinking about how we could "translate" the change description into other shapes - especially regarding the array dot notation.

So - how is this update description calculated?